# Pandas python data analysis

Tags: python, pandas

I'm tasked with working on the second half of a code that will allow the user to take the computer path that was been created then read all those csv files then combine them all in a new dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

# Define the path where the CSV files are located
csv_path = '/c/Users/Sudent/Documents/data/'

# Get a list of all CSV files in the specified path
csv_files = glob.glob(csv_path)

# Create an empty list to store the individual DataFrames
dataframes = []

# Read each CSV file and store its DataFrame in the list
for file in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    dataframes.append(df)

# Concatenate all DataFrames into a single DataFrame
combined_df = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)

# Print the combined DataFrame
print(combined_df)
```

ValueError: No objects to concatenate
Expecting the code to combine all the csv into a data frame and print the combined dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Here is an error as you are not using the correct `URL or path` you should mention `.csv`.

As,

```
 csv_path = '/c/Users/Sudent/Documents/data/*.csv'
```

Here is the updated code:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

# Define the path where the CSV files are located
csv_path = '/c/Users/Sudent/Documents/data/*.csv'

# Get a list of all CSV files in the specified path
csv_files = glob.glob(csv_path)

# Create an empty list to store the individual DataFrames
dataframes = []

# Read each CSV file and store its DataFrame in the list
for file in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    dataframes.append(df)

# Concatenate all DataFrames into a single DataFrame
combined_df = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)

# Print the combined DataFrame
print(combined_df)
```

Hopefully, this will help you.